# How to filter a map with Java stream api?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(1, "f");
  map.put(2, "I");
  map.put(3, "a");
  map.put(4, "c");....etc
```

Now I have a list:

```
List<Integer> picks = {1,3}
```

I would like to get back a list of Strings, ie, values from map that matches the key values, found in the 'pick' list.So, **I am expecting to get back {"f", "a"} as result**. Is there a way to use **java stream api** to do it in elegant way?

When there is one value , I am doing it this way:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
   .filter(entry -> "a".equals(entry.getValue()))
   .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But getting hard time when there is a list of keys/picks to filter with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `List.contains()` in the `Stream#filter` to only accept those values which are present in the list:

```
List<String> result = map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .filter(ent -> picks.contains(ent.getKey()))
   .map(Map.Entry::getValue)     
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this by using something like this :

```
List<String> values = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> picks.contains(entry.getKey()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

values.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
f
a
```

However it might not be efficient as `List::contains` is O(N). Consider using a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) (for example [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html)) instead of `List` for `picks` as `HashSet::contains` is O(1).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to traverse the entire map just to collect picked values. Rather iterate over the required keys and grab the relevant values from the map. If the map is far more larger compared to the values you need to pick which is usually the case, then this approach should outperform the other. Moreover this solution is much more compact and has less visual clutter to me. Here's how it looks.

```
List<String> pickedValues = picks.stream().map(map::get)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is a very good solution. However you should also filter out `null` values after `map` operation as `Map::get()` will return `null` for non existing keys in the map for values from `picks`.