# How obtain a Set of Strings from a Map of objects with a string property

Tags: java, filter, collections, java-stream

I need to get a `Set<String>` with the `accountNumbers` from the given `Map<String, Account>` and filter the *map contents* by retaining only *active accounts* (`active == true`) so that there will be no inactive accounts.

**Account** *class* has the following attributes:

```
private String number;
private String owner;
private double balance;
private boolean active = true;
```

My solution so far looks like this:

```
public Set<String> getAccountNumbers() {
    return new HashSet<String>(accounts.values().stream().filter(Account::isActive));
}
```

I tried casting, but that didn't seem to work. Can somebody tell me, how I access the attribute number from here on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter a map with Java stream api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597518/how-to-filter-a-map-with-java-stream-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply `map` in order to transform the stream of accounts `Stream<Account>` into a stream of strings `Stream<String>`. And then apply the terminal operation `collect` to obtain a `Set` as a result of the execution of stream pipeline.

Your attempt to pass the stream to the constructor of the `HashSet` is incorrect (it expects a `Collection`, not a `Stream`) and unnecessary.

**Note:** stream without a ***terminal operation*** (like `collect`, `count`, `forEach`, etc.) will *never get executed*. `map` and `filter` are called ***intermediate operations***.

```
public Set<String> getAccountNumbers() {
    return accounts.values().stream()    // Stream<Account>
            .filter(Account::isActive)
            .map(Account::getNumber)     // Stream<String>
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

[*For more information on streams take a look at this tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/)